# How to decode b'a\xXX format

Tags: python, binary, zlib

I'm trying to read data from .db3 file, this is how I get each row in database
.db3 the table is MBinary and the column is five_bboxes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiN96.png)
con = sqlite3.connect(fileName)
cursorID = con.cursor()  # to record ID

```
    cursor = con.cursor()  # to get data

    cursor.execute('SELECT five_bboxes FROM MBinary')

    for row in cursor.fetchall():

        zobj = zlib.decompressobj()
        unknown_data = zobj.decompress(row[0])
        print(f"unknown_data:{unknown_data}")
```

OUTPUT:

unknown_data:b'a\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x00\x00\x00\xb5\x00\x00\x00\xf3\x02\x00\x00\xa3\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x00\x00\x00\xf6\x02\x00\x00u\x00\x00\x00\xd4\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00\xd7\x00\x00\x00\xe6\x00\x00\x00e\x01\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00n\x02\x00\x00\xf1\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x02\x00\x00'

Answer (score 0):

The `b'foo'` stuff is how Python formats a byte array for printing, so what you have there is most likely a `bytes` object. These are described in the ["Built-in Types"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) section of the [Python library reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

The [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) of the standard library *may* be useful in decoding the bytes to something useful, but that depends entirely on what those bytes represent and how it is encoded, which is not a Python question.